# How to set the directory where JVM stores MDMP files

Tags: java, jvm, environment-variables, dump

I have an application that where the Java Runtime Environment frequently runs out of memory. The JVM dumps then the memory into a MDMP file.

The problem is that this MDMP-files are stored in the Windows/System32 directory. The directory and the drive is soon full.

How can I set a different directory for storing MDMP files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the Java -XX options [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html):

Those might be interesting in your setting:

```
-XX:HeapDumpPath=
-XX:ErrorFile=
```