# Can I set the output location of a JVM crash minidump?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, jvm-arguments, jvm-crash, minidump

We are currently experiencing a JVM crash with Java 8u60 32-bit that we are attempting to debug. In order to do this I need to create a minidump using the JVM command line argument -XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash. Our operating system is write protected so as to avoid corruptions. I won't go into detail there but this causes any minidumps to get deleted any time the system reboots.

I want to change the output directory and naming scheme of the dump to a location on a non-write protected SSD with drive letter D:. This will greatly improve the likelyhood of getting a crash dump I can use.

Is it possible to do this with JVM arguments? I know its possible to do with general crash reports using the -XX:ErrorFile argument (I am already doing this) so I am wondering if its possible to do the same with a minidump.
I've checked some documentation but haven't been able to find anything about it there or online.

At this point I am assuming its not possible but maybe someone here can shed some light on the concrete facts? Any links to documentation I may have missed would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the directory where JVM stores MDMP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666412/how-to-set-the-directory-where-jvm-stores-mdmp-files)

Comment: @haba713 I don't think that parameter is what I am looking for, but it looks like someone marked this question as one that already has an answer. Looking at that answer it seems like it's not possible to change the output directory sadly. Not sure why I wasn't able to find that question originally.

Answer (score -2):

To change the destination of the jvm crash log run java with this option:

```
java -XX:ErrorFile=/path/to/file.log -jar myapp.jar
```